# AttachEventListener('change' ...) not working in IE9 with dropdown select/ion

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, addeventlistener

I am using the below code (simplified version) and it works in old and new firefox (3.6 and 12), and in IE7 and IE8. But not in IE9.

```
if (aDropdown.addEventListener)
   aDropdown.addEventListener("change", function(){alert("please work");} , false);
else
   aDropdown.attachEvent("onchange", function(){alert("please work");} );
```

What could be the problem here? I tried using single quote (') for `change` and `onchange`, but no luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Did you add this one on the top of the html, so that it can run as standard mode?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, unfortunately it started working properly now ... (???), I checked the top and it did have that:
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`